# What are the advantages (or needs) of using tornado with Pusher for a Django application?

Tags: django, tornado, pusher

We are a small team starting to plan how to develop a chat service in Django using Pusher to push the messages in real time.

So far we understand that we need an asynchronous way of pushing the messages to the Android and web browsers clients and we've chosen a hosted solution (Pusher) instead of implementing our own, probably using sockjs and tornado. We thought we didn't need Tornado for anything now that we have Pusher!.

In the Python module documentation (https://github.com/pusher/pusher_client_python) there is only small mention to Django, there is however a Tornado section which says:"To use the Tornado web server to trigger events... ". So we wonder why would we need or what use does it have to use Tornado to Trigger the events from our server to Pusher.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only scenario I can imagine is when you need to trigger multiple messages at once, then tornado being asynchronous is obviously more beneficial then django (or any other synchronous web framework), since the latter would have to trigger message and wait for response every time.

Comment: I guess so, but when our app server triggers messages to pusher the response expected from pusher is an "OK, received" that should be given to our server, for each message, without any delay. I mean: when the clients are waiting for a new message in a chat, I can see the advantage of having an asynchronous system and a way of pushing the messages in order not to block the server while there isn't a response to deliver.. but I can't see the need when you are expecting and instant response from the other side! Do you think Tornado could perform better in this situation?? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Well now thinking about it better (and thanks to your answer) it is clear that any time you pull to an external service you have to expect a delay, and it would be much more efficient to handle other requests while pusher send us the response for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

The linked document just means that if you are using both Pusher and Tornado, you should do this extra bit of configuration to make Pusher work nicely with Tornado's non-blocking model.  Frameworks that use synchronous concurrency don't need any extra work so they don't need to be mentioned specifically in the docs.  You can continue to use Tornado or Django (or Flask, etc) depending on your preferences and the needs of your application.